# array of text files in C++ 2010

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 8 text files (that are existed in my program file) and I want to assign them in an array. But I encounter this error:
(A value of type "char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "int").
each of my files has at most 15 character

```
char *ArrTemp[8][15];//[number of strings][max size of every string]
char temp1[] = "temp1.txt"; 
char temp2[] = "temp3.txt";
char temp3[] = "temp5.txt";
char temp4[] = "temp7.txt";
char temp5[] = "temp9.txt";
char temp6[] = "temp11.txt";
char temp7[] = "temp13.txt";
char temp8[] = "temp15.txt";
ArrTemp[8][15] = {temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};
```

Comment: You need `const char* temp1 = "temp1.txt"; ` etc. and `const char *ArrTemp[8];`

Comment: Also note `{temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};` can only appear in initialization, such doesn't work for assignment.

Comment: I recommend declaring the texts as `static const`, example: `static const temp1[] = "temp1.txt";`  The `static` means only one instance.  The `const` means read-only.  This allows the compiler to place the data in a read-only segment of your executable.  The compiler can emit code to directly access the instance rather than as some compilers do, reserve space on the stack and copy the literal to the stack.

Comment: Since you are using C++ you might also want to look into std::vector and std::string.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ArrTemp[8][15] = {temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};
```

is not right. It is not initialization. It tries to assign the RHS to the LHS.

Remove the line

```
char *ArrTemp[8][15];//[number of strings][max size of every string]
```

and then, use:

```
char* ArrTemp[8] = {temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};
```

or simply

```
char* ArrTemp[] = {temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `const` in there somewhere because the literals are constant characters?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, when you use `char temp1[] = "temp1.txt";` a copy of the string literal is made for `temp1`, which can be modified.

Comment: The downside is the array will be sized to fit the source string, resulting in either extra book-keeping or a length-guessing minefield if the user wants to change those strings later.

Comment: @user4581301, I agree.They definitely have the option of specifying the size of the array explicitly to gain a bit of flexibility. `char temp1[ARRAY_SIZE] = "temp1.txt";`

Comment: I overlooked that in my own answer. Thanks. Wee edit coming.

Answer (score 0):

In the earlier example, the variable ArrTemp is declared as a char pointer, but used as a two dimensional char array, which throws an error. You can try using array of pointers to store character strings of diverse lengths. Please refer to the code below:

```
char temp1[] = "temp1.txt";
char temp2[] = "temp3.txt";
char temp3[] = "temp5.txt";
char temp4[] = "temp7.txt";
char temp5[] = "temp9.txt";
char temp6[] = "temp11.txt";
char temp7[] = "temp13.txt";
char temp8[] = "temp15.txt";

char *ArrTemp[] = {temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp4,temp6,temp7,temp8};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of misconceptions here that are not being addressed. But first, the elephant:

[std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is much safer and makes almost all of this dead easy.

```
char *ArrTemp[8][15];//[number of strings][max size of every string]
```

Does not make an array of c-style strings. Note that the type is `char *`. It makes an 8x15 array of pointers to c-style strings. Depending on what you want, you can either.

```
char ArrTemp[8][15];
```

Allocate storage for 8 14 char c-style strings (one character is always lost to the terminating NULL). You will then have to copy the strings into the array, but you have total control over the storage can change the contents of the array. If you don't know what the file names will be at this point and just want storage, this is the c-style array way to go.

or

```
char * ArrTemp[8];
```

Which will create an array of 8 pointers to c-style strings which you will then have to point to strings.

Next,

```
char temp1[] = "temp1.txt";
```

Makes a 10 character array and copies "temp1.txt" into it. If you ever want to change temp1, you better remember that it's 10 characters because if you

```
char * ArrTemp[] = 
{
    temp1,
    ...
}
```

easy access to the size of temp1--`sizeof(temp1)`--is lost. `sizeof(ArrTemp[0])` will return the size of the pointer to temp1, probably 4 or 8 bytes, not `sizeof(temp1)`.

Which means one more modification is required.

```
char temp1[16] = "temp1.txt";
```

You must predefine the size of the array. Note I went with 16 to fit the terminating NULL. but 16 is an ugly solution. There is the potential to have many of the 16s floating around in the code and what happens when you want 21 later? You have to hunt all the 16s down and change them. Not a good idea, so yet another slight modification:

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 15
```

and

```
char temp1[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1] = "temp1.txt";
```

Again, +1 for the null.

But...

If temp1 is never to be changed you can

```
const char * temp1 = "temp1.txt";
```

Then, with a slight modification to ArrTemp, you can

```
const char * ArrTemp[] = 
{
    temp1,
    ...
}
```

But if you have done that, then you can save yourself some trouble and define the c-style strings directly in ArrTemp.

```
const char *ArrTemp[]
{
    "temp1.txt",
    "temp3.txt",
    "temp5.txt",
    "temp7.txt",
    "temp9.txt",
    "temp11.txt",
    "temp13.txt",
    "temp15.txt",
};
```

Back to std::string.

This makes all of the above mutable-immutable, "What size is my char array?" problems go away.

```
std::string ArrTemp[]
{
    "temp1.txt",
    "temp3.txt",
    "temp5.txt",
    "temp7.txt",
    "temp9.txt",
    "temp11.txt",
    "temp13.txt",
    "temp15.txt",
};
```

You have 8 strings preloaded into ArrTemp. The strings can be changed. The length of the string doesn't matter. If you try to overfill std::string, it gets bigger. You'll probably have to run the computer out of RAM to push past it's capacity. You can take advantage of std::string's library of tools like `+` to append and `=` to assign.

Much cleaner and easier to use.